# update_option() updating the option with an empty value?

Tags: plugin-development, options

I have a call to [update_option()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_option) inside a class which edits some keys from the options array passed to it and then saves the updated array to the database, I don't have any fancy code, the function is only calling the `update_option()` function like this:

```
update_option( 'my_options', $this->updated_options );
```

Now this class is initialized in an admin page:

```
$instance = new My_Class($options_to_update);

$instance->init(); // the function that updates the option is called here
```

The thing is that `update_option()` is returning `true` and updating the option with an empty value.

also I checked the array just before the call to this function and nothing is wrong:

```
print_r( $this->updated_options );
```

I also tried to update with a string:

```
update_option( 'my_options', 'any string' );
```

Now my questions are:

- Am I doing something wrong ?
- Is there a specific time to call `update_option()` ? because I have it in a function hooked to `admin_init` and it's working fine.

**Update:**

I found out that it's not working only if i's called inside the display function of `add_menu_page()` any reason why ? the passed value is always `null`.

Comment: And you are not using `'pre_update_option_' . $option` filter, somwhere in your code ?, to make sure you are getting proper value for function call, you can check the value received on filter `'pre_update_option_' . $option`

Comment: @sven I didn't know about that, I just tried it and dumped the first parameter `$new_value` and it's showing `null`, I also tried it with a hard coded string.

Comment: did you tried the same outside the class?, Also if it works properly outside the class and not in class, you would need to provide the code.

Comment: @sven yes, I have another class which adds a hook to `admin_init` to add the default value if this option doesn't exist or empty, and it's working fine.

Comment: @sven I just tested `update_option()` manually from the page and it's also showing `null` and what I found is, this is only happening inside the display function of `add_menu_page()`, I don't know why it's not working inside of it.

Comment: by display function means, you are extending WP_List_Table in your class, also please can you show me your code? because I can't replicate the problem on my local setup and untill than I can't help.

Comment: Post the code for your class. It is impossible to see what is happening.

Comment: I tried calling 'update_option('test_option', 'test');` inside my submenu page class `display()` function which extends `WP_List_Table` and it works.